# Copying file from app bundle of sandboxed application

Tags: macos, bundle, sandbox

I have a graphical application with some predefined tool configurations. At the first lunch of the application I would like to copy these default configuration files into ~/Library/Containers//Data/Library/... from the inside of the bundle. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it'll help you.

```
-(void)copy
{
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *path = [self getPath];
    BOOL sucess = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path];

    if(!sucess){
        NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/*put your assets name with extension here */"];
        sucess = [filemanager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:path error:&error];
        if (!sucess) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
-(NSString *) getPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/*put your assets name with extension here */"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice piece of code. Is it also possible to do in C++? So far I managed to do all by c++. A few minutes ago I also fond out I can not even read receipt file stored at /Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt. Would your obj C code allow me to read from other than Resources directory?